Implementing a 'soft exception' in Guidewire ContactManager - how?
In Guidewire ContactManager, we are trying to implement a "soft exception".  By this I mean we want a DisplayableException to appear when a certain condition arises when creating or updating a contact, but after clicking "Update" a second time, we want the DisplayableException to not appear any longer and the contact to be created.
Any GW gurus out there run into this kind of req't before and if so what did you do?  Ideally if this could be implemented in a Rule (.grs file) that'd be great but we also are using an Enhancement class extending ABContact that we could always move our functional code into if that needs to be done.

Validation rules. Reject with a warning. There will be a warning message that can be dismissed and then the user can still move forward with the update.
See the documentation here:
https://docs.guidewire.com/self-managed/cc/1023/rules/gosuRules/cc/topics/r_fz17108710.html
To reject with a warning, for example, you could do this within a validation rule. There are other reject methods that also specify the exact field causing the issue you can use if you desire.
contactObject.reject(null, null, ValidationLevel.TC_LOADSAVE, "your warning message")
You pass null to the error fields (first 2 fields in the method) because you want the rejection to be non-blocking.

Thanks, Steve!  Alas I tried this and don't get a displayed exception.  The rejection doesn't even appear in the chatter.  Here's my implementation:

if (softWarning.length > 0) {
aBContact.reject(null, null, ValidationLevel.TC_LOADSAVE, softWarning)
}

Where did you put the call to the reject method? In a new validation rule right? Also, for this to work in ContactManager, you may have to add some ValidationLevels to the typelist. Any contact that has already been saved to the DB has passed the Loadsave level already. Also what is the "certain" condition you are trying to check for. A little more context might help.

ATM we've implemented a static var in a helper class that is used to track the new Contact being created.  The var is an ArrayList and each time a new Contact is started it gets added to the list if there's the soft exception displayed.  If the user clicks "Save" again the Contact is removed from the list and the save is permitted.  This is less than ideal and we're hoping to find a less fraught way of doing it.

Yeah, as you said, this is probably not the ideal way to do this. What exactly is the condition you are checking for (to display the soft exception)? Is this condition being checked anytime a contact is updated or at most 1 time per contact? The static var might not work in all situations because each ContactManager node will have it's own instance of this static var.

What you have coded is attempting to recreate a feature of all InsuranceSuite validation processing that has been in place for a long time.  Please review the link Steve shared and implement your validations using the ootb framework instead of reinventing the wheel this way.  I know the IS products are complex and it takes time to utilize all of their capabilities but you are creating unnecessary and fragile code when the solution has already been provided for you to use.

@MartinAavik Thanks for your commentary.  Could you please post sample code or a link to same?  Thank you.

Steve provided a code sample in his original answer.  Implement this in the Validation ruleset and you're all set.

@MartinAavik I tried that and alas, it didn't work.

I'm stumped @MattCampbell .  Can you confirm this is your workflow?  1. you added a validation rule to the ABContactValidationRules ruleset in CM Studio.  2. After restarting CM you logged into the CM UI and started adding an ABContact.   3. When clicking "Save" (up update, etc) you see a validation error on the screen that blocks the save.  4.   When you click save again the same error appears and continues to block your progress.  If this is what you're seeing can you share what code you have in your ABContactValidationRule?  Or open a ticket with GW Support for more direct assistance.
